# C++ custom type for vector class

Tags: c++11, vector

I have a very simple struct A and want to use it in a vector, say std::vector. How should I define the required copy/move constructors and assignments? I tried either not define copy/move constructor or assignment or define them explicitly. But either way does not work. This should be a very simple thing to do. I am very shocked I can not get it work!

- not define copy/move constructor or assignment

  ```
  struct A  
  {
    std::string key;
    std::string key2;

    A() {};
    A(std::string key, std::string key2): key(key), key2(key2) {};
  };
  ```
- with user define copy/move constructor and assignment

  ```
  struct A
  {
    std::string key;
    std::string key2;

    A() {};

    A(std::string key, std::string key2): key(key), key2(key2) {};

    A(const A& other): key(other.key),key2(other.key2){} ;
    A& operator=(const A& other) {
         key = other.key;
         key2 = other.key2;
         return *this;
    };

    A(A&& other): key(std::move(other.key)),key2(std::move(other.key2)){} ;
    A& operator=(A&& other) {
      if (this == &other)
         return *this;

      key = std::move(other.key);
      key2 = std::move(other.key2);
      return *this;
    };
  };
  ```

I also tried to use default move/copy constructor and assignment, by assign "=default" to these four functions. Did not help.

Where struct A is used

```
    class B {
    private:
      std::vector<A> A_v;
    public:
      // first call preAllocate, to preallocate and initialize 1000 entries.
      void preAllocate(){
        A_v.resize(1000);
      }

      // call addA() with id starting from 0. If fewer than 100 entries are 
      // left, call resize() to expand. 
      // We don't know the total number of entries for A.
      // and addA() is called out of order in turn of id, 
      // so, I couldn't use push_back().
      void addA(int id, A& a){

        assert(id < A_v.size());
        A_v[id].key = a.key;
        A_v[id].key2 = a.key2;

        if (A_v.size() - id < 100)
           A_v.resize(A_v.size() + 100);
      }
    };
```

When I ran the program, I saw segmentation fault error, because of the vector::resize() call.

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. [Switching to
>   Thread 0x7fffe97fa700 (LWP 88073)] 0x00007ffff7b91268 in
>   std::basic_string, std::allocator
>
> > ::basic_string(std::string const&) ()    from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (gdb) bt
> >     #0  0x00007ffff7b91268 in std::basic_string, std::allocator
> >     ::basic_string(std::string const&) ()    from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
> >     #1  0x000000000041e02f in A::A (this=0x7ffff7ef2ee0, 
> >         other=...) at objrecipe.h:34
> >     #2  0x0000000000430d88 in std::_Construct > (
> >         __p=0x7ffff7ef2ee0) at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_construct.h:75
> >     #3  0x000000000042fb5f in std::__uninitialized_copy::__uninit_copy
> >     (__first=0x7ffff7f8fee0, __last=0x7ffff7fab210, 
> >         __result=0x7ffff7ec0010)
> >         at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:75
> >     #4  0x000000000042db7f in std::uninitialized_copy (__first=0x7ffff7f5d010, __last=0x7ffff7fab210,
> >     __result=0x7ffff7ec0010)
> >         at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:125
> >     #5  0x000000000042ae5a in std::__uninitialized_copy_a (__first=0x7ffff7f5d010, __last=0x7ffff7fab210, 
> >         __result=0x7ffff7ec0010)
> >         at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:278
> >     #6  0x00000000004272f0 in std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a > (__first=0x7ffff7f5d010, 
> >         __last=0x7ffff7fab210, __result=0x7ffff7ec0010, __alloc=...)
> >         at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:301
> >     #7  0x0000000000423520 in std::vector >::_M_default_append (this=0x7ffff268cb78, __n=1000)
> >         at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/vector.tcc:561
> >     #8  0x000000000041f821 in std::vector >::resize (this=0x7ffff268cb78, __new_size=21000)
> >         at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:676
> >     #9  0x000000000041e3d5 in B::addA (this=0x7ffff268cb60, 
> >         id=19002, e=...) at filesrc.h:143

Or this error.

> #0  0x00007ffff620f067 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
>       at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
>   #1  0x00007ffff6210448 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
>   #2  0x00007ffff624d1b4 in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=1, 
>       fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff6342210 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n")
>       at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
>   #3  0x00007ffff625298e in malloc_printerr (action=1, 
>       str=0x7ffff6342318 "double free or corruption (!prev)", 
>       ptr=) at malloc.c:4996
>   #4  0x00007ffff6253696 in _int_free (av=, p=, 
>       have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3840
>   #5  0x000000000041f598 in A::~A (this=0x7fffc032d410, 
>       __in_chrg=) at objrecipe.h:23
>   #6  0x000000000042dd9e in std::_Destroy (
>       __pointer=0x7fffc032d410) at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_construct.h:93
>   #7  0x000000000042b0e9 in std::_Destroy_aux::__destroy (
>       __first=0x7fffc032d410, __last=0x7fffc0344920)
>       at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_construct.h:103
>   #8  0x00000000004275a1 in std::_Destroy (
>       __first=0x7fffc02f28a0, __last=0x7fffc0344920)
>       at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_construct.h:126
>   #9  0x00000000004236b7 in std::_Destroy (
>       __first=0x7fffc02f28a0, __last=0x7fffc0344920)
>       at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_construct.h:151
>   #10 0x000000000042380f in std::vector >::_M_default_append (this=0x7ffff268cb78, __n=1000)
>       at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/vector.tcc:576
>   #11 0x000000000041fa6b in std::vector >::resize (this=0x7ffff268cb78, __new_size=21000)
>       at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_vector.h:676
>   #12 0x000000000041e5ae in B::addA (this=0x7ffff268cb60, 
>       id=19001, e=...) at filesrc.h:112

Comment: Could you show us the call sequence for `preAllocate()` and `addA()`?
Also, why not just use `push_back()` and rely on implicit resizes, which in general would perform better (and are less error-prone). Lastly, have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: Are you using this struct  from single or from multiple threads ?

Comment: My educated guess: you are corrupting the heap elsewhere in your program, possibly in a completely unrelated part of code. This `resize()` call is merely an innocent victim that happens to hit the corrupted part of the heap.

Comment: Enable all warnings. You are comparing signed with unsigned values. In addA if id is negative you will crash the program. Also be sure to run in debug mode else the assert is not used. You should check for overflow not with asserts only.

Comment: @tomix86: as an example: main thread calls preAllocate(1000). then create 10 child threads, each child thread processing an A (a request, eg.). Each child thread will call addA(id, A& a) when it completes processing that request. I can not use push_back() because I want the vector to store requests in order but the threads may call addA() out of order.

Comment: @StPiere pointed out the problem! Many threads are calling addA() and they may call resize() simultaneously! This led to Segmentation fault or double free errors! After I put a mutex to protect the resize, I can run the program now. It is not a C++ problem. It is a multi-threading problem. Thanks everyone for your suggestions! I really appreciate it!